# Rudin 8.7 (c) trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

I am struggling to understand an aspect of a proof from rudin, Why does $E(4ix)=-1$ imply (c)?

[image]

Comment: His argument shows that the only real value assumed by $E(it)$ for $0 < t < 2\pi$ is $-1$, hence in particular it never equals $1$ in that interval.

Comment: @Bungo thanks! Could you also explain how $E(4it)$ being real implies $x^2-y^2=0$?

Comment: If $E(it)=1$, then $E(4it)=(E(it))^4=1$, but $E(4it)=-1$, if it were real. The assumption that $E(4it)$ is real implies that $4xy(x^2-y^2)=0$. Since $x,y>0$, then the only factor that can be zero is $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: If $E(4it)$ is real, then its imaginary part $4ixy(x^2 - y^2)$ is zero. So either $xy$ is zero or $x^2 - y^2$ is zero. If $xy$ is zero, then one of $x$ or $y$ must be zero. But as he says, "our preceding work shows that $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 1$", hence $xy$ can't be zero.

Comment: @Bungo If you make these an answer I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin's argument shows that the only real value assumed by $E(it)$ in the interval $0 < t < 2\pi$ is $-1$, hence in particular it never equals $1$ in that interval.

A second question was raised in the comments:

> Could you also explain how $E(4it)$ being real implies $x^2 - y^2 = 0$?

If $E(4it)$ is real, then its imaginary part $4ixy(x^2 - y^2)$ is zero. So either $xy$ is zero or $x^2 - y^2$ is zero. If $xy$ were zero, then one of $x$ or $y$ would have to be zero. But as Rudin says, "our preceding work shows that $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 1$", hence $xy$ can't be zero. Therefore $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.

Comment: While it can be shown that $E(it)$'s only real value on $(0,2\pi)$ is $-1$, Rudin's argument doesn't pass through that statement. Instead it is for $E(4it)$ the one for which that statement is proven.

Comment: @plop Does the argument not show that for $0 < t < \pi/2$, the only real value assumed by $E(4it)$ is $-1$? And does it not follow from this that for $0 < t < 2\pi$, the only real value assumed by $E(it)$ is $-1$? Or is there a subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: That the last statement is neither the final statement that they want (c) nor and intermediate one that is needed. It is true, but not really part of their argument.